# droppable on colored background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would I alter the following code so only cells with the yellow background will be droppable?

Is there an easy way to do this or would I have to recode the entire jquery?
Thanks.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLb3H/38/

html:

```
<table border="1" id="tbl">
 <tr>
  <td ></td>
  <td  bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
  <td class="items  p1 p3"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft- scraps/32/Button-Blank-Red-icon.png"/></td>      
</tr>

<tr>      
  <td bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
  <td class="items  p1"></td>
  <td class="items p3" bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
</tr>

<tr>      
  <td class="piece" id="p1" ><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Button-Blank-Gray-icon.png"></td>
  <td bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
  <td class="piece" id="p3" ><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Button-Blank-Gray-icon.png" ></td>
</tr>
```

jquery

```
$('img').draggable({
});

$('#tbl td').droppable({
hoverClass: 'over',
drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).children('img').remove();
    var cell = ui.draggable.appendTo($(this)).css({
        'left': '0',
        'top': '0'
    });

  $('img').draggable('disable');

$("td").each(function() {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("."+id).css("background", "");        
  });

}
});

$(".piece").mouseover(function() {
id = $(this).attr('id');
$("."+id).css("background", "yellow");
}).mouseleave(function() {
id = $(this).attr('id');
$("."+id).css("background", "");       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have different ways to achieve this:

#### Short version

```
//All elements with yellow background
$('#tbl td[style*=background-color:yellow]').droppable();
```

#### Using filter

```
$(function() {
    $('#tbl td').filter(function () {
        return $(this).css('background-color') == 'yellow';
    }).droppable();
});
```

#### Using find:

```
jQuery('#tbl').find('td').each(function (){
    if($(this).css('background-color') == 'yellow'){
       // do something like $(this).droppable();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Each time I tried to adapt the solution to my current code the program lost all the other functionality. Perhaps this is happening b/c cells only turn yellow the mouseover event? Is there a way to check for dropable inside of mouseover?

Comment: I add the following code in the drop function:        
  if ($(this).css("background-color")==='rgb(255, 255, 0)') {
The alert () is only being displayed when  dropped on a yellow background.  here is the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLb3H/41/
How would I make the piece revert to it’s original location, or should I post a new question?
Thanks.